# I have inserted the Facebook-Like button code into Kompozer but nothing happens?

Tags: facebook-like

I have copied and inserted the Facebook-Like codes into my Webpage (Kompozer) and nothing happens. There is no like button only a blank space where the first code should be.
Why is this happening?
Thank you for your help and replies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following code is right below the opening body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then place the following where you want the like button to display:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

If this doesn't work, please show us your code. Also look in javascript console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately kompozer do this kind of thing. So, the way to insert the facebook codes into your html document is when finished, using a text editor like gedit or notepad.